# Помогите написать сочинение-рассуждение, хотя бы помочь с идеей

Tags: фразеология, литература, текст

Короче, надо взять любой адекватный афоризм и написать по нему 3 доказательства (желательно нормальных): согласен с этим афоризмом. Или написать 3 доказательства (опровержения): не согласен с этим афоризмом.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Берем первого попавшегося плохого писателя и его первый афоризм. Писатель: Пабло Коэльо.
Афоризм: Если человек действительно чего-то захочет, то вся Вселенная будет способствовать тому, чтобы его желание сбылось.
Аргумент против 1: Больные раком(на финальной стадии) дети не хотят жить? Как Вселенная способствует тому, чтобы больные раком дети не умерли? Они недостаточно хотят или недостаточно пытаются осуществить желание? Есть много примеров того, как люди чего-то желают, но это желание физически неосуществимо.
Аргумент против 2: А почему Вселенная способствует, а не сопротивляется. Можно найти случаи спортсменов, когда те очень хотели добиться результата, у них все выходило, но они получали травму, несовместимую с продолжением карьеры. То есть они очень хотели, делали максимально верные и эффективные действия, а Вселенная взяла и все испортила максимально грубым образом.
Аргумент против 3: А почему вся Вселенная? Если вы боретесь с коллегой за определенную должность, строя друг против друга коварные планы, то получается, что есть силы во Вселенной, которые сопротивляются вашему рьяному желанию. В данном примере не вся Вселенная способствует вашему желанию. Если много людей будут хотеть всякого, то их желания будут противоречить друг другу. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что вся Вселенная не может способствовать большинству желаний.

Comment: Ахахаха, спасибки огромное. Я хз, у меня репутация меньше 15, но я влепил бы вам лайк)